# Как реализовать систему баллов?

Tags: php, javascript

Типа за какие-то действия зачислять определенную сумму баллов,
например, за переход по ссылке.

Comment: Создаёшь промежуточную страницу, при переходе на которую будут зачислятся балы и будет выполнятся переадресация на нужную страницу.

Answer (score 1):

```
// создаем файл к примеру link.php
// пишем такой вот код
// то есть при переходе
// по link.php?url=http://site.ru
// начислим баллы  и отправим по ссылке

$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? trim($_GET['url']) : null;

if (!empty($url)) {

    // добавляем баллы 
    # запрос в бд

    // и отправляем на другую страницу
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;

}
```

Comment: А если за различные ссылки, разное качество баллов?